# messages file is not picking single quote

Tags: playframework-2.6

In `Play Framework`, the `messages` file is used for localisation. I have added the following key-value in it but the single quote in the value is not getting picked.

```
error.incorrectTag = The specified tag doesn't exist in the system
```

When I print the above message using the following code

```
println(s"${messagesApi("error.incorrectTag")(langs.availables(0))}")
```

I see `The specified tag doesnt exist in the system` (single quote is not there)

How can I print the single quote?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the single quote `'` by using a double single quote `''` like this:

```
error.incorrectTag = The specified tag doesn''t exist in the system
```